# É possível utilizar o validador W3C para sites construídos em Angular.JS?

Tags: angularjs, w3c-validador

Tenho um projeto, que foi feito em Angular.JS. Ao lançar o projeto no [validador da W3C](https://validator.w3.org/) eu recebo diversos erros que eu não teria como tratar.

Por exemplo:
**Erros de Atributos:** `ng-controller` | `ng-cloak` | `ng-model` | `ng-click` | `ng-if` | `ng-repeat` Erro: Attribute not allowed on element.

**Bad Value:** Geralmente nos href's, ou src's preenchidos de uma variável do angular `{{minhaVariacel}}`

Existe alguma possibilidade a se tratar para que eu possa validar e obter o selo do W3C de um site com Angular.JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme o link do [Angular Guide Normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization)

A normalização faz:

1. Remove `x-` e `data-` da frente dos elementos e atributos.
2. Converte o `:`, `-`, ou `_` delimitado para `camelCase`.

Então para validar basta adicionar `data-` na frente dos atributos, pois os atributos com prefixo `data-` são validos no HTML5.

Então o próprio *AngularJS* irá "normalizar" para funcionar **como se não houvesse** `data-`, ficando assim:

- `data-ng-controller=""`
- `data-ng-cloak=""`
- `data-ng-model=""`
- `data-ng-click=""`
- `data-ng-if=""`
- `data-ng-repeat=""`

E para o `src=` e `href=` adicione `data-ng-` no prefixo, assim:

- `data-ng-src=""`
- `data-ng-href=""`

Pronto, seu site deve validar.